# Reference error with Fluent NHibernate 1.0 RTM and Visual Studio 2010 beta 2

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, c#-4.0, visual-studio-2010

I have a weird reference error when I use Fluent NHibernate 1.0 RTM and Visual Studio 2010 beta 2.
Basically I have tried following the getting started tutorial on Fluent NHibernate's page and it doesn't compile. I get those two reference error on Visual Studio :

> Warning    1   The referenced assembly "FluentNHibernate" could not be resolved because it has a dependency on "System.Data.OracleClient, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" which is not in the currently targeted framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client". TestFluentNHibernate
>
> Warning    3   The referenced assembly "FluentNHibernate" could not be resolved because it has a dependency on "System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" which is not in the currently targeted framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client".   TestFluentNHibernate

I don't really understand why those two assembly are needed to use FluentNHibernate, but I find it even weirder that it doesn't get the assemblies.

I have created a simple console application by the way.

Thank you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

By default Visual C# 2010 targets the ".Net Framework 4 Client Profile" which is a subset of the full ".Net Framework 4" and is missing both of those assemblies.

Go to the Project Menu, and select menu item /Your Proj Name/ Properties... On the application tab change the Target framework: from .NET Freamework 4 Client Profile to .NET Framework 4.

This is my first project with any of Visual /anything/, NHibernate, Fluent etc so it took a while to figure out and Google couldn't find me answers anywhere, so hope this helps.

Comment: Great! Thank you, I didn't know about this "Client Profile".
For more information about what Client Profile is :
http://blogs.msdn.com/jgoldb/archive/2009/05/27/net-framework-4-client-profile-introduction.aspx

Comment: I just ran into this issue.  Thanks for clearing this up!  A better error message would be nice from Microsoft.

Comment: +10 if I could. Thanks a ton for getting me out of that bind!

Answer (score 0):

@David,

Thanks, your comment was a lifesaver.

Weird though, My project ran fine yesterday, did a rebuild today and BAM, 29 errors all to doe with not finding the NHibernate / fluent / etc references.

Changing the settings you mentioned helped.